# pairwise analysis in R

Tags: r

I have a large data-frame in which I have to find the columns when both rows are equal for pairs of individuals.

Here is an example of the dataframe:

```
>data
     ID pos1234 pos1345 pos1456 pos1678
 1    1       C       A       C       G
 2    2       C       G       A       G
 3    3       C       A       G       A
 4    4       C       G       C       T
```

I transformed the dataframe into a pairwise matrix with:

```
apply(data, 2, combn, m=2)


      ID  pos1234 pos1345 pos1456 pos1678
 [1,] "1" "C"     "A"     "C"     "G"
 [2,] "2" "C"     "G"     "A"     "G"
 [3,] "1" "C"     "A"     "C"     "G"
 [4,] "3" "C"     "A"     "G"     "A"
 [5,] "1" "C"     "A"     "C"     "G"
 [6,] "4" "C"     "G"     "C"     "T"
 [7,] "2" "C"     "G"     "A"     "G"
 [8,] "3" "C"     "A"     "G"     "A"
 [9,] "2" "C"     "G"     "A"     "G"
[10,] "4" "C"     "G"     "C"     "T"
[11,] "3" "C"     "A"     "G"     "A"
[12,] "4" "C"     "G"     "C"     "T"
```

I am now having trouble identifying the column containing the identical letters between pairs. For example, for pairs `1` and `2` the columns containing the identical letters would be `pos1234` and `pos1678`.

Would it be possible get a dataframe with just identical letters for each pair of individuals?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to `combn`:

```
res0 <- combn(nrow(data), 2, FUN = function(x) 
  names(data[-1])[ lengths(sapply(data[x,-1], unique)) == 1 ], simplify=FALSE)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] "pos1234" "pos1678"

[[2]]
[1] "pos1234" "pos1345"

[[3]]
[1] "pos1234" "pos1456"

[[4]]
[1] "pos1234"

[[5]]
[1] "pos1234" "pos1345"

[[6]]
[1] "pos1234"
```

To figure out which of these [[1]]..[[6]] correspond to which pairs, take `combn` again:

```
res <- setNames(res0, combn(data$ID, 2, paste, collapse="."))
```

which gives

```
$`1.2`
[1] "pos1234" "pos1678"

$`1.3`
[1] "pos1234" "pos1345"

$`1.4`
[1] "pos1234" "pos1456"

$`2.3`
[1] "pos1234"

$`2.4`
[1] "pos1234" "pos1345"

$`3.4`
[1] "pos1234"
```